# Error : Invalid multibyte character in parser at line~

Tags: r

I have a that working well in R ver 3.6.3.

And 1 Weeks ago I download R ver 4.0.0 because I replace my old computer with new one.

Then Suddenly my all code work very poor in R 4.0.0!

When I first search this error, most of people recommend some ways that is related to UTF-8

But What is very annoying is I'm already set my environment! Using Global option tap or else..

I tried to almost everything which is related UTF-8, but It never works.

Also, I tried to update packages tool already but again it never works.

Then Sometimes, I found somethings very strange by chance.

That is,

1. when I randomly push 'enter' key, suddenly the error didn't pop up!

But I can't find the exact reason why this was happened.

2. when I paste this code in R ver 3.6.3, It works very nicely! WHAT IS THE REASON!!!
3. This is same code but, when I tried to execute this code just changing the blank (I mean \r\n(?) \n(?) anyway..) Sometimes the code didn't work, Other times the code works.

This makes me crazy now I don't know the reason
Please help me

The code below is the code what I mentioned until now.

And I attached the picture that is the outcome in R ver 4.0.0

Thank you for reading.

```
Jeokhap <- function(target_pdf){

  target <- target_pdf

  page_jeok_1 <- grep("(4.{0,3}|라.{0,3})\\s{0,}이 (집합투자..|투자신탁)에 적합한 투자자 유형",target)

  for (k in 1:(length(target)-page_jeok_1)){

    if(length(grep("11.{0,3}매입,\\s{0,1}환매",target[(page_jeok_1+k)]))>0){

        page_jeok_2 <- page_jeok_1+k

        break
    }

  }

  app_list_jeok=c()

  for (k in page_jeok_2:page_jeok_1){

    app_list_jeok <- append(target[k],app_list_jeok)

  }

  outcome_jeok <- paste(app_list_jeok,collapse="")


  ####extract sentence
  check_jeok <- gregexpr("(4.{0,3}|라.{0,3})\\s{0,}이 (집합투자..|투자신탁)에 적합한 투자자 유형(.*?)11.{0,3}s{0,1}매입,\\s{0,1}환매",outcome_jeok)
  sentence_choose_jeok3 <- regmatches(outcome_jeok,check_jeok)

  if(length(regexpr("위험\\s{0,}\\등급\\s{0,}분류\\s{0,}기준",sentence_choose_jeok3))==1){

    sentence_choose_jeok3 <- gsub("위험\\s{0,}\\등급\\s{0,}분류\\s{0,}기준.*","",sentence_choose_jeok3)
  }else if(length(regexpr("위험\\s{0,}\\등급\\s{0,}분류\\s{0,}기준",sentence_choose_jeok3))>1){

    sentence_choose_jeok3 <- sub("(위험\\s{0,}\\등급\\s{0,})(분류\\s{0,})(기준)","\\1\\2의 기준",sentence_choose_jeok3)

    sentence_choose_jeok3 <- gsub("위험\\s{0,}\\등급\\s{0,}분류\\s{0,}기준.*","",sentence_choose_jeok3)
  }


  if(length(regexpr("투자\\s{0,}\\위험\\s{0,}등급\\s{0,}기준",sentence_choose_jeok3))==1){

    sth1 <- gsub("투자\\s{0,}\\위험\\s{0,}등급\\s{0,}기준.*","",sentence_choose_jeok3)
  }else if(length(regexpr("투자\\s{0,}\\위험\\s{0,}등급\\s{0,}기준",sentence_choose_jeok3))>1){

    sentence_choose_jeok3 <- sub("(투자\\s{0,}\\위험\\s{0,})(등급\\s{0,})(기준)","\\1\\2의 기준",sentence_choose_jeok3)

    sentence_choose_jeok3 <- gsub("투자\\s{0,}\\위험\\s{0,}등급\\s{0,}기준.*","",sentence_choose_jeok3)
  }


  return(1)
}
```

[image: Executed code in R 4.0.0]